# SimpleDateFormat is not parsing the milliseconds correctly

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

**Background:**

In my database table, I have two timestamps

```
timeStamp1 = 2011-08-23 14:57:26.662
timeStamp2 = 2011-08-23 14:57:26.9
```

When I do an "ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC", timeStamp2 is considered as the greater timestamp(which is correct).

**Requirement:** I need to get the difference of these timestamps (timeStamp2 - timeStamp1)

**My implementation:**

```
public static String timeDifference(String now, String prev) {
    try {
        final Date currentParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(now);
        final Date previousParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(prev);
        long difference = currentParsed.getTime() - previousParsed.getTime();
        return "" + difference;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

The answer should have been 238ms, but the value that is returned is -653ms.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: `The answer should have been 232ms`, really - I get 900-662 = 238.

Comment: If they're stored as timestamps in the database, why do you get them as Strings to transform them into Dates? Just get them as Timestamp instances, and you'll have two comparable dates without a need to parse any string. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29

Comment: Thomas- Yeah, sorry, that was a typo. It is 238ms

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but the JavaDoc states this:

> For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

This indicates that the milliseconds from `2011-08-23 14:57:26.9` would be parsed as `9` instead of `900`. Adding the trailing zeros might work: `2011-08-23 14:57:26.900`.

Comment: I'm adding the zeros and it works alright. But, is it the right way of handling it?

Comment: Internally, `NumberFormat.parse("9")` is called, thus there's no way other than adding the trailing zeros.

Comment: @dkulkarni - the correct way would be to do as already commented: do not handle timestamps as String. Read and handle them as java.sql.Timestamp, eventually converting to java.util.Date!

Comment: I think I will go with adding zeros for now. Thanks Thomas

Comment: Adding zeros changes this from 9 milliseconds to 900. If the value doesn't matter, then fine, but otherwise you will get an incorrect value.

Comment: @RobertCasto the value does matter, but "26.9" being parsed as 26.009 is already incorrect, as it is not the expected result.

Comment: i have this `2014-12-03 04:40:00` after parsing using SimpleDateFormat and date.getTime returns this `1417563600000`. this miliseconds are wrong as it is actually `12/2/14 6:40 PM` according to this http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm

Comment: @MuhammadBabar that's not exactly the same topic, but you should take timezones etc. into account. You seem to get a difference of exactly 10 hours, which indicates a difference in timezones used - either when parsing or on that site.

Comment: @Thomas i have been testing it for like 2 months oct(10)-nov(11) it was working fine but on dec(12) the problem arise. After debugging i can see my date object have information right information i.e correct date and time but getTime returning wrong miliseconds!

Comment: I solved it actually the problem was 12 hour format. i need to pass 16 instead of 4. As it was taking 4 as 4 am!

Answer (score 19):

The format you are parsing and the format uses doesn't match.  You expect a three digit field and are only providing one digits.  It takes `9` and assumes you mean `009` when what you want is `900`.  Date formats are complicated and when you prove dates in a different format it may parse them differently to you.

The documentation says `S` means the number of milli-seconds and the number in that field is 9, so it is behaving correctly.

---

EDIT: This example may help

```
final SimpleDateFormat ss_SSS = new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SSS");
ss_SSS.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
for (String text : "0.9, 0.456, 0.123456".split(", ")) {
  System.out.println(text + " parsed as \"ss.SSS\" is "
      + ss_SSS.parse(text).getTime() + " millis");
}
```

prints

```
0.9 parsed as "ss.SSS" is 9 millis
0.456 parsed as "ss.SSS" is 456 millis
0.123456 parsed as "ss.SSS" is 123456 millis
```

Comment: So, how should I be handling this scenario? As of now, I'm manually adding the trailing zeros. Is that really the right way to go?

Comment: You have to give the date string in the expected format. If you changed the order of the day, month or year you wouldn't expect it to just "know" what you mean. Adding zeros is likely to be the simplest solution.

Comment: I think the problem happens when I'm entering the data into the database. The value that is going into the DB is actually 2011-08-23 14:57:26.900. I'm using an H2 db and it is removing the trailing zeros. So, when I do a fetch from the db, i get 2011-08-23 14:57:26.9

Comment: Can you extract the date from the DB as a Timestamp via JDBC instead of using a String? This would avoid the need to convert/parse the date/time.

Comment: @dkulkarni Do you put a `Date` and fetch a `String`? If not, you might have the database column have the corresponding datatype, i.e. `timestamp` for `Date` (retrieve a `Date` then) or `(var)char` and use `String` always.

Comment: @Peter - The formats DO match, the number of letters is ignored for parsing (for numbers, month and year are exceptions), not expecting any field length. Doc: `...For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored...`

Comment: @Carlos, The format the OP uses assumes a one digit number has a different meaning to how SimpleDateFormat parses it. They cannot match because `For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored` i.e. You cannot tell it that `9` means `900` ms.

Comment: but I meant that `SSS` in the pattern matches (by definition) `9`, or `662` or `123456`... If it does not match, SimpleDateFormat throws an Exception.

Comment: @Carlos, actually it doesn't. It will take the number and makes that the milli-seconds.

Comment: @Peter - I believe we have a language problem here. I know it will take the number, but for that it must match the pattern! My problem with that answer was only about the use of : match". When I wrote "match" I meant it from the SimpleDateFormat view, meaning "it can be parsed according the given format string, each format field matches a sequence of the input string". So IMO it must match for it to take the number and make that the milliseconds. But this is leading nowhere.

Comment: @Peter I had a similar problem when I was trying to PARSE data according to that format.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It handles these situations properly. In the following example, the milliseconds are correctly parsed as 200ms.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class ParseMillis {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "00:00:01.2";
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.S");
    DateTime dateTime = format.parseDateTime(s);
    System.out.println(dateTime.getMillisOfSecond());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with too accurate time from my logfiles with 6 digit milliseconds. Parsing Time gave up to 16 minutes difference! WTF?

```
16-JAN-12 04.00.00.999999 PM GMT --> 16 Jan 2012 04:16:39 GMT
```

Changing the number of digits reduced the erroneous difference and thanks to this thread I could identify the problem:

```
16-JAN-12 04.00.00.99999 PM GMT --> 16 Jan 2012 04:01:39 GMT
16-JAN-12 04.00.00.9999 PM GMT --> 16 Jan 2012 04:00:09 GMT
16-JAN-12 04.00.00.999 PM GMT --> 16 Jan 2012 04:00:00 GMT
```

As `SimpleDateFormat` internally handles only 3 digits I removed the unnecessary with a small regex (ignoring round-off errors, working for 1 up to *n* digits):

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*( [AP]M)", "$1$2");
```

Thanks to @Peter Lawrey for your answer, prevented me going insane :-)