# Jackson not parsing Timestamp correctly

Tags: java, jackson, timestamp, datetime-parsing, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm having trouble parsing `java.sql.Timestamp` from XML files using Jackson 2.8.5. Somehow the milliseconds are padded with zeros on the left side.

Here is a minimal example showing that :

```
public class Foo {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ts")
    Timestamp ts;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String xml = "<Foo><ts>2017-09-21T11:25:32.1Z</ts></Foo>"
        Foo foo = new XmlMapper().readValue(xml, Foo.class);
        System.out.println("foo.ts = " + foo.ts);
    }
}
```

> foo.ts = 2017-09-21 11:25:32.001

Whereas if I parse the string manually, I get the expected value

```
System.out.println(Instant.parse("2017-09-21T11:25:32.1Z"));
```

> 2017-09-21 11:25:32.1

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a problem with `SimpleDateFormat` (which is used internally by Jackson), as [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7160014/7605325). I've also made a test with plain Java (without Jackson) and the error also occurs:

```
String s = "2017-09-21T11:25:32.1Z";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SX").parse(s);
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime())); // 2017-09-21 08:25:32.001
```

If you can change the xml, adding zeroes to the input (`2017-09-21T11:25:32.100Z`) works.

---

Another alternative is to write a custom deserializer for your field (using the proper methods in `Timestamp` class to convert from `Instant`):

```
public class CustomTimestampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(p.getText()));
    }
}
```

Then you annotate the field to use this custom deserializer:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ts")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTimestampDeserializer.class)
Timestamp ts;
```

Now, when printing the `Timestamp`, you get the correct value:

> 2017-09-21 08:25:32.1

*Wait a minute, why the hour is `08`?* - That's because when you `System.out.println` a `Timestamp`, it implicity calls the `toString()` method, and this method converts the `Timestamp` to the JVM default timezone (in my case, it's `America/Sao_Paulo`, so it's correct, because 08:25 AM in São Paulo is equivalent to 11:25 AM in UTC). But the value kept by the `Timestamp` is correct.

*You can read more about this behaviour of `toString()` in [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) - it talks about `java.util.Date`, but the idea is the same (specially because `Timestamp` extends `Date`, so it has the same problems).*

---

To serialize it back to xml, you can configure a custom serializer as well:

```
public class CustomTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(value.toInstant().toString());
    }
}
```

Then you annotate the field to use this serializer:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ts")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTimestampDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomTimestampSerializer.class)
Timestamp ts;
```

Just a detail: `Instant.toString()` will result in `2017-09-21T11:25:32.100Z`. If you don't want those extra zeroes in the end, you can customize the format using a `DateTimeFormatter`. So the custom serializer will be like this:

```
public class CustomTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        // date/time
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        // nanoseconds without leading zeroes (from 0 to 9 digits)
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
        // offset (Z)
        .appendOffsetId()
        // create formatter (set zone to UTC to properly format the Instant)
        .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(fmt.format(value.toInstant()));
    }
}
```

This will print the timestamp as `2017-09-21T11:25:32.1Z`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer ! I'm aware of the alternative of using custom (de)serializers but I don't want to go that way. I also lied in my question, it was really printing `2017-09-21 09:25:32.1` and not `2017-09-21 11:25:32.1` but I'm aware of timezone issues so I faked it ;-) I think this might be a bug, I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/264).

Comment: @cheseaux Apparently, it seems to be a problem with `SimpleDateFormat` (which is used internally by jackson): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7160014/7605325 - I've just tested with plain Java (without jackson) and it has the same problem. Anyway, I've updated the answer, adding this info

Comment: @cheseaux I've opened an issue in Oracle and [they accepted](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8188772), which strongly suggests that the problem is really in `SimpleDateFormat` class (which is used internally by Jackson). Probably the best alternative in this case is to use the custom (de)serializers.