# Move milliseconds by one position value

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, milliseconds

as a result of ["incorrect" java parsing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159895/simpledateformat-is-not-parsing-the-milliseconds-correctly) (my fault) I now have several thousands of entries in oracle DB with incorrect timestamp.
The issue is as follows:

Timestamp of 2018-06-26 11:15:43.**950** has been inserted into DB as
26-FEB-18 11.15.43.**095**000000 AM

Is there any function for narrowing the milliseconds? I only figured out that with some to_char , to_date functions combined with substring i could "remove" the 0 in front of the miliseconds but it seems to me as not good enough resolution.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Unfortunatelly, I can not re-upload data with corrected algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option: reload data from original source, after you fix your code.

If you no longer have access to the original data, and you must fix it all in place, use the UPDATE statement below (shown in context):

```
create table tbl ( ts timestamp );

insert into tbl ( ts ) values ( timestamp '2018-06-26 11:15:43.0950' );
commit;

select ts from tbl;

TS                                     
----------------------------------------
2018-06-26 11.15.43.095000000         

update tbl set ts = ts + 9 * (ts - cast(ts as timestamp(0)));

1 row updated.

commit;

select ts from tbl;

TS                                     
----------------------------------------

2018-06-26 11.15.43.950000000
```

Explanation:

If your original timestamp was of the form `X + w`  where `X` is down to whole seconds, and `w` is the fractional second part, the current value is `X + z`, where `z = w/10`. (You added an errant `0` right after the decimal point, which means you divided `w` by ten). So: you currently have `X + z` but you want `X + w`, or in other words, `X + 10 * z`. So, you must add `9 * z` to what you already have.

To get `z` (the fractional part of the timestamp) you need to subtract `X` (the integral part) from the timestamp. `X` itself is the truncation of the timestamp to whole seconds. There is no `TRUNC()` function to truncate to whole seconds, but the `CAST` function to `TIMESTAMP(0)` does that job quite well.

To use your sample data: `X` is the timestamp `'2018-06-26 11:15:43.000000'`. This is also the result of `cast(ts as timestamp(0))`. `w` is `.9500` and `z` is what made it into your table, `.0950`. Your current value is `X + z`, but you want `X + w`. That is `X + 10 * z = (X + z) + 9 * z`, and now remember that `(X + z)` is just `ts` (the value you have in the table currently) so you only need to add nine times the value `z`, which is the difference `(ts - X)`.

Comment: Wow, just wow :) Eventhough I read your explanation several times I am still confused about how it works but the update section is working flawlessly :)

Comment: @Alone89 - OK, I added a paragraph showing who `X`, `w` and `z` are in the specific example from your question (and from my demo).

Comment: Aaaah now I get it :) Now i see why is your nick mathguy as this solution has not come into my mind in any scenario ever :D Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRUNC( time, 'MI' )` to get the time without the seconds component (as a Date datatype, which you can then use `CAST` to convert back to a Timestamp). You can then use `EXTRACT( SECOND from time )` to get the seconds (including fractional seconds) component and split that into a seconds and milliseconds components (the latter you can just multiply by 10 to perform your correction) and then use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to convert the numeric values to an interval which can be added to the truncated timestamp.

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8bbb/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE times ( time ) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-06-26 11:15:43.095' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT time,
       CAST( TRUNC( time, 'MI' ) AS TIMESTAMP )
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
           TRUNC( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM time ) )
           + MOD( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM time ), 1 ) * 10,
           'SECOND'
         ) As updated_time
FROM   times
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8bbb/11/0)**:

```
|                    TIME |           UPDATED_TIME |
|-------------------------|------------------------|
| 2018-06-26 11:15:43.095 | 2018-06-26 11:15:43.95 |
```

You may, however, be better just uploading the timestamps from your source data again (if you can) with a corrected algorithm as you will have lost the least-significant digit from the milliseconds.

Comment: Wow, superb thanks - that's the answer I have been looking for. Also thanks for sql fiddle link :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your data is forever corrupted. There's no way of distinguishing between shifted timestamps and proper ones:

```
2018-06-26 11:15:43.950 
2018-06-26 11:15:43.095
```

both result in the following timestamp

```
26-FEB-18 11.15.43.095000000 AM
```

Comment: Yes from the perspective of application that's true. Luckily I have many data logged in DB and I can distinguish the corrupted one by simply comparing the timestamp on log reply (which if is correpted is smaller) and timestamp on log request)

Comment: That's important, because otherwise it would be impossible to find which rows need fixing.